# OpenCV VideoCapture Wrapper Class

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to make a "wrapper" of the VideoCapture class of OpenCV, but I can't get it correctly working, my code is as follows:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

class wrapper
{
    private:
        cv::VideoCapture cap;
        int device_id;

    public:
        wrapper();
        ~wrapper();

        void setup(int _device_id);
};

// wrapper.cpp

wrapper::wrapper()
{
    device_id = 0;
}

wrapper::~wrapper()
{
    cap.release();
}

wrapper::setup(int _device_id)
{
    device_id = _device_id;
    cap = cv::VideoCapture(device_id);

    cout << "Checking device" << endl;
    if(!cap.isOpened())
    {
        cout << "Couldn't open device" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Device opened " << endl;
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't open the device. I have checked my device on the starter_video.exe (OpenCV examples) and it does open.

Any thoughts?

Comment: btw `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` includes everything. If you wanna include the core only, `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>` or #including highgui is not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never try to assign a videocapture like you do.
Please, try to replace the line :

```
cap = cv::VideoCapture(device_id);
```

by

```
cap.open(device_id);
```

Comment: Also, cap.release() is not necessary as it will be released anyway, and you spared the destructor.